# Find cartesian product of the elements in a program generated dynamic "sub-list"

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

I have a program which producing and modifying a list of "n" elements/members, n remaining constant throughout a particular run of the program. (The value of "n" might change in the next run).

Each member in the list is a "sub-list"! Each of these sub-list elements are not only of variable lengths, but are also dynamic and might keep changing while the program keeps running.

So, eventually, at some given point, my list would look something like (assuming n=3):

```
[['1', '2'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
```

I want the output to be like the following:

```
['1ax', '1ay', '1az', '1bx', '1by', '1bz',
 '1cx', '1cy', '1cz', '1dx', '1dy', '1dz',
 '2ax', '2ay', '2az', '2bx', '2by', '2bz',
 '2cx', '2cy', '2cz', '2dx', '2dy', '2dz']
```

i.e. a list with exactly (2 * 3 * 4) elements where each element is of length exactly 3 and has exactly 1 member from each of the "sub-lists".

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product

lst = [['1', '2'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['x', 'y', 'z']]
output = [''.join(p) for p in product(*lst)]
#  OR
output = list(map(''.join, product(*lst)))

# ['1ax', '1ay', '1az', '1bx', '1by', '1bz', 
#  '1cx', '1cy', '1cz', '1dx', '1dy', '1dz', 
#  '2ax', '2ay', '2az', '2bx', '2by', '2bz', 
#  '2cx', '2cy', '2cz', '2dx', '2dy', '2dz']
```

A manual implementation specific to strings could look like this:

```
def prod(*pools):
    if pools:
        *rest, pool = pools
        for p in prod(*rest):
            for el in pool:
                yield p + el
    else:
        yield ""

list(prod(*lst))
# ['1ax', '1ay', '1az', '1bx', '1by', '1bz', 
#  '1cx', '1cy', '1cz', '1dx', '1dy', '1dz', 
#  '2ax', '2ay', '2az', '2bx', '2by', '2bz', 
#  '2cx', '2cy', '2cz', '2dx', '2dy', '2dz']
```